# HTML Local Storage parameter replacement escaping

Tags: sql, sqlite, html

I'm experimenting with a simple HTML5 local storage based app and I'm having trouble with the parameter replacement escaping (maybe) in my code.

The SQL line I want to execute is:

`SELECT name, title FROM testTable WHERE name LIKE '%test%';`

so my Javascript line is something like:

`tx.executeSql( "SELECT name, title FROM testTable WHERE name LIKE '%?%'", [ search_string ],`

This fails (I think) because the `?` is being treated as a literal and so the parser complains about too many parameters (`search_string`).

I optimistically tried using `???` and `["'%", search_string, "%'"]` but same result.

Any suggestions - I imagine it's something really obvious so please be gentle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
tx.executeSql( 
    "SELECT name, title FROM testTable WHERE name LIKE ?", 
    [ '%'+search_string+'%' ]
    );
```

Comment: I thought it might be something obvious! Thank you Ned.  I'm surprised that doesn't end up as as SQL string ending in "LIKE %foo%" which I thought was invalid - I thought you needed ' around the string.  Nevertheless, it works for me.

Comment: @speewell You should mark his answer as the accepted one and probably give up an upvote, then :)

Comment: @speedwell: when you use parameter replacement like this, it takes care of building the entire string literal, including the necessary quotes.

Comment: @MattC - Marked as accepted but evidently I need a reputation of 15+ to upvote - will come back when I've reached that level.